# Published app not showing in Play Store on Chromebook devices

Tags: google-play, chromebook

We have published an education app on Google Play Store. It shows in Play Store but not on any Chromebook devices. We tried every Chromebook-specific setting in Unity as well as in the custom manifest file. Here is the published app manifest, can anyone help out with what we are missing that is making it incompatible with Chromebook devices? NOTE: We sideloaded the APK file on the actual Chromebook device and it's working fine.

```
<manifest
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:versionCode="46"
android:versionName="1.7.46"
android:installLocation="0"
android:compileSdkVersion="32"
android:compileSdkVersionCodename="12"
package="com.medcerts.aandp"
platformBuildVersionCode="32"
platformBuildVersionName="12">
<application
    android:label="(reference) @0x7f030005"
    android:icon="(reference) @0x7f020000"
    android:debuggable="false"
    android:extractNativeLibs="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="unity.allow-resizable-window"
        android:value="false"/>
    <meta-data
        android:name="unity.launch-fullscreen"
        android:value="true"/>
    <meta-data
        android:name="unity.splash-enable"
        android:value="true"/>
    <meta-data
        android:name="unity.splash-mode"
        android:value="0"/>
    <receiver
        android:name="com.unity.androidnotifications.UnityNotificationRestartOnBootReceiver"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:exported="false"/>
    <receiver
        android:name="com.unity.androidnotifications.UnityNotificationManager"
        android:exported="false"/>
    <activity
        android:theme="(reference) @0x7f040001"
        android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:launchMode="2"
        android:screenOrientation="0"
        android:configChanges="40003fff"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
        android:resizeableActivity="false">
        <meta-data
            android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity"
            android:value="true"/>
        <intent-filter>
            <category
                android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            <action
                android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="false"/>
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-feature
    android:name="org.chromium.arc"/>
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="30000"/>
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"
    android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch"
    android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch.distinct"
    android:required="false"/>
<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true"/>
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="26"
    android:targetSdkVersion="32"/>
```

Comment: I would like to try it on my Chromebook, so please let me know the app ID. The ID is the end of the app URL. For example, **jp.co.yamamoto.norio.japanesekanjitranslation**.

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.medcerts.aandp this is the published version. In the play console it shows that it supports 58 out of 59 total Chromebook devices. But the model that I am using, it shows unsupported. Here is the Chromebook that I am using https://www.amazon.in/gp/product/B09LVP7KZG/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o01_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

If you want I can share the internal review build, for that I need you to add you to the internal test group in play console.

Comment: When I look at your app in Google Play on my "ASUS Chromebook C223NA" it says it is not compatible.
I checked the devices.csv of my app.
It seems to be incorrect. It includes 59 different Chromebooks but obviously not enough.
It does not include my Chromebooks either. My app is so simple that probably all Chromebooks should be supported.
Can you email Play Console or Unity with your questions?

Comment: Yes, I already emailed Google regarding the same but did not receive any response from them yet. Is there any way to make it visible on all devices? I see a lot of other apps in Chromebook playstore and I believe it automatically shows up in new devices.